# JavaScript Validation Issue - HTML form submits even when incomplete

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm new to JavaScript and am struggling to wrap my head around this one.

I have an HTML form with some required input fields which have `onblur` validation. I want to fix my code so that when the form is submitted without a user having filled in those required fields, the error messages show up instead of the form actually submitting like it is currently.

I realise similar questions have been asked however I was unable to implement suggested methods and have been researching this for days. I also require a pure JavaScript method, so how can I ensure all of the empty required fields throw their error messages when the submit button is clicked?

This is my first time posting a question - I hope I've covered everything, please let me know if I need to include anything else! Thanks in advance.

```html
<form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="contact.html" novalidate>
  <p>Text</p>

  <div class="form-group">
    <select name="flights" size="1">
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Flight</option>
      <option value="helicopter">Helicopter</option>
      <option value="aerobatic">Aerobatic</option>
      <option value="tramping">Tramping</option>
      <option value="amphibian">Amphibian</option>
      <option value="glider">Glider</option>
      <option value="private-charter">Private Charter</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Flight Duration</label>
    <br>
    <select name="flight-duration" size="1">
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select Duration</option>
      <option value="helicopter">1 Hour</option>
      <option value="tramping">2 Hours</option>
      <option value="amphibian">3 Hours</option>
      <option value="glider">Custom</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Booking Date</label>
    <br>
    <select id="dayDropDown">
    </select>
    <select id="monthDropDown">
    </select>
    <select id="yearDropDown">
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="firstname"></label>
    <input id="firstname" type="text" onblur="blur()" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required autofocus minlength="2">
    <span id="firstname-error"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lastname"></label>
    <input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required minlength="2">
    <span id="lastname-error"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="phone"></label>
    <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required minlength="8">
    <span id="phone-error"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email"></label>
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter valid email address" required>
    <span id="email-error"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="country"></label>
    <input id="country" type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country" required minlength="2">
    <span id="country-error"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea placeholder="What can we do for you?"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
/****************
     *FORM-VALIDATION*
     ****************/

//convert user input to upper case

function addFormValidation(theForm) {
  if (theForm === null || theForm.tagName.toUpperCase() !== 'FORM') {
    throw new Error("expected first parameter to addFormValidation to be a FORM.");
  }

  theForm.noValidate = true;

  theForm.addEventListener('submit', function (evt) {
    var isError = false;

    var elements = this.elements;
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i += 1) {
      if (!isFieldValid(elements[i])) {
        isError = true;
      }
    }

    if (isError) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    }
  });

  function isFieldValid(field) {
    var errorMessage = "";

    function isFieldValid(field) {
      if (!needsToBeValidated(field)) {
        return true;
      }

      if (field.id.length === 0 || field.name.length === 0) {
        console.error("error: ", field);
        throw new Error("found a field that is missing an id and/or name attribute." +
                        " name should be there. id is required for determining the field's error message element.");
      }

      field.classList.remove('invalid');

      var errorSpan = document.querySelector('#' + field.id + '-error');

      if (errorSpan === null) {
        console.error("error: ", field);
        throw new Error("could not find the '#" + field.id + "-error' element. It's needed for error messages if #" + field.id + " is ever invalid.");
      }
      errorSpan.classList.remove('danger');
      errorSpan.innerHTML = "";

      if (field.minLength > 0 && field.value.length < field.minLength) {
        errorMessage = "Must be " + field.minLength + " or more characters long.";
      }

      if (field.maxLength > -1 && field.value.length > field.maxLength) {
        errorMessage = "Must be " + field.maxLength + " characters or less.";
      }

      if (field.type === "email" && !isEmail(field.value)) {
        errorMessage = "This should be a valid email address.";
      }

      if (field.required && field.value.trim() === "") {
        errorMessage = "This field is required.";
      }

      if (errorMessage !== "") {
        field.classList.add('invalid');

        errorSpan.classList.add('danger');
        errorSpan.innerHTML = errorMessage;
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    }


    //fields that do not require validation

    //        function needsToBeValidated(field) {
    //            return ['submit', 'reset', 'button', 'hidden', 'radio', 'fieldset', 'select'].indexOf(field.type) === -1;
    //        }
    function needsToBeValidated(field) {
      return ['submit', 'reset', 'button', 'hidden', 'fieldset'].indexOf(field.type) === -1;
    }

    //email regx pattern to ensure email input is a valid email

    function isEmail(input) {
      return input.match(/^([a-z0-9_.\-+]+)@([\da-z.\-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,})$/);
    }

    //add onblur validation to provide error/success info for user
    var elements = theForm.elements;
    for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
      elements[j].addEventListener('blur', function () {
        isFieldValid(event.target);
      })
    };
  }

  //wait for content to load before loading form

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    addFormValidation(document.querySelector('#contact-form'))
  });

  /***********************************************
         * Implemented this date selector script for use on contact form:
         * Drop Down Date select script- by JavaScriptKit.com
         * This notice MUST stay intact for use
         * Visit JavaScript Kit at http://www.javascriptkit.com/ for this script and more
         ***********************************************/

  var monthtext = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

  function populatedropdown(dayfield, monthfield, yearfield) {
    var today = new Date()
    var dayfield = document.getElementById(dayfield)
    var monthfield = document.getElementById(monthfield)
    var yearfield = document.getElementById(yearfield)
    for (var i = 0; i < 31; i++)
      dayfield.options[i] = new Option(i, i + 1)
      dayfield.options[today.getDate()] = new Option(today.getDate(), today.getDate(), true, true) //select today's day
      for (var m = 0; m < 12; m++)
        monthfield.options[m] = new Option(monthtext[m], monthtext[m])
        monthfield.options[today.getMonth()] = new Option(monthtext[today.getMonth()], monthtext[today.getMonth()], true, true) //select today's month
        var thisyear = today.getFullYear()
        for (var y = 0; y < 20; y++) {
          yearfield.options[y] = new Option(thisyear, thisyear)
          thisyear += 1
        }
    yearfield.options[0] = new Option(today.getFullYear(), today.getFullYear(), true, true) //select today's year
  }

  //populatedropdown(id_of_day_select, id_of_month_select, id_of_year_select)
  window.onload = function () {
    populatedropdown("dayDropDown", "monthDropDown", "yearDropDown")
  }
```

Comment: `I was unable to implement suggested methods` - why? Also, any errors in the `console`?

Comment: @MoshFeu No errors in the console, however I did receive a warning when I used Closure Compiler which says 'possible inexistent property'... This is the code it is referring to:  
if (field.minLength > 0 && field.value.length < field.minLength) {
                errorMessage = "Must be " + field.minLength + " or more characters long.";
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call your javascript validation function in you code.

```
<form name="" method="" onsumbmit="return myfunction()">
 <!-- Your code -->
</form>
```

And in your javascript code, if everything is right then return true else return false and display appropriate message.

```
function myfunction(){
    <!-- here your validation conditions -->>
    if(everything==ok)
    return true;
    else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Pirate, I'm still a bit confused though. I added the onsubmit="return isFieldValid()" as this was the function with the validation conditions and now the onblur validation doesn't work... The form doesn't submit with empty fields though so we're half way there!

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `novalidate` attribute on your form.